# Is it possible to extract sass without compiling to css with webpack?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I have a webpack build where I want to keep the same js bundle files that webpack generates, but I also need to generate multiple versions of my styles using different SASS variable values. In other words, I'd like my webpack output to be `bundle.js` and `bundle.scss` so that I can compile `bundle.scss` in a subsequent (non-webpack) process, e.g. using the lib-sass compiler directly.

I know about the ExtractTextWebpackPlugin, and I tried that with the `raw-loader` but no luck. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: { test: /\.s?css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({  loader: "raw-loader"  }) } This worked for me perfectly, my output file contains unprocessed sass

Comment: @AvcS ok, must be something wrong with my configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I must have had something else wrong, because raw-loader worked afterall.  Cheers